# Would it make sense to prolong bounty time limit for large bounties?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

There are some annoyances that would require more than just a casual google or from the top of the head answer. Some questions and problems require effort in answering, and the bounty system helps getting these questions answered.

However, for annoyances that are really hard to solve, I would be ready to put a bounty of hundreds if not thousands of points. If only the bounty could stand for more than a week; a week is short time to get a complex problem of a user solved remotely.

Would it be possible / would it make sense to prolong the time for which a bounty of 500 or more stands?

Comment: If a week seems too short for you, I suggest you set a smaller bounty at first and when you don't get any positive feedback, you can then put a larger bounty. If you are desperate for an answer, you have to part with some virtual points.

Comment: Sure. I have no problem offering even 1k. However, I would prefer them all to go to the person who finds the solution at last; if I give a bounty 4 x 250 on 4 consecutive weeks, the person to solve will get only 250, instead of the 1000 that she earned in my eyes and that I have used.

Comment: I think what should matter more is whether you get the answer you wanted. If the answer is really good and you want to reward it, you can put on an additional bounty to reward the answerer.

Comment: Might make sense to break it up into separate questions too. If it takes a week to answer one question then perhaps it's too broad.

Comment: OK, I will give you [an example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/181676/how-to-disable-touchpad-while-using-trackpoint-on-a-thinkpad). This is a question I would be willing to assign half of my points to, but it is quite clear that the problem is not trivial and would take many hours to solve.